# Exploring Matrix Powers with Wolfram (using Sum Notation)

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, summation

I am trying to gain an intuition for what algebraically happens to a square matrix (say a $2$-dimensional square matrix) when it is successively multiplied by itself. I have used

```
m = Table[Subscript[\[Omega], i, j], {i, 2}, {j, 2}];
Manipulate[MatrixForm@Expand@MatrixPower[m, k], {k, 0, 5, 1}]
```

to show the expansion of the matrix after raising it to the 0th through 5th power.  Here's the 3rd power to show how complicated it gets:

> [image]

This is too complicated for me to discern a pattern, but my guess is that a pattern *does* emerge if we somehow tidy up this notation using $\sum$ notation.

**Question:** Does Wolfram provide some way of easily converting the above MatrixPower into a form using $\sum$ notation?

Comment: You could try using `FindSequenceFunction[]` on the matrix entries to find a general formula, but I'm usually pessimistic about finding general formulae for things of this sort, unless the matrix has some sort of structure (e.g. triangular, Hermitian, etc.).

Comment: Running `FindSequenceFunction` on the top-left matrix element (i.e. `Table[ First@First@Expand@MatrixPower[m, k], {k, 0, 
   10}] // FindSequenceFunction`) just hangs on my machine. I'm assuming it doesn't turn up anything on more powerful machines.

Comment: Well, for 2 by 2 matrices that is easy because they can be analytically diagonalized. Even more insight can be gained by expanding in terms of the [Pauli matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have answer for using Sigma notation but in case of finding pattern, converting existing matrix cells to some graphic maybe become helpful.

For example instead of using this form:

[image]

Use these:

[image] , [image]

For power of 2, results are:

[image] , [image]

Here is the interface of the code to play:

[image]

Code:

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{vars, shapes}, 
  vars = Table[
    Subscript[w, i, j], {i, 1, dimension}, {j, 1, dimension}];
  shapes = 
   Transpose[
     Append[{Flatten@vars}, 
      If[useNumber == 1, 
       Text[Style[#, Bold, 16]] & /@ Range[1, dimension^2], 
       MatrixPlot[#, FrameTicks -> None, ImageSize -> 20] & /@ 
        Table[ArrayReshape[
          RotateRight[PadLeft[{1}, dimension^2], i], {dimension, 
           dimension}], {i, 1, dimension^2}]]]] /. {x1_, x2_} -> x1 -> x2;

  Column[{Subsuperscript["M", ToString@dimension <> "x" <> ToString@dimension, power], 

    Grid[(MatrixPower[vars, power]) /. shapes, Frame -> All, 
     FrameStyle -> Directive[LightGray, Thick]]}]], 
     {{dimension, 2, "Dimension"}, 2, 5, 1}, 
     {{power, 1, "Power"}, 1, 5,  1}, 
     {{useNumber, 0, "Use number"}, {0, 1}}]
```

Comment: This doesn't *quite* answer the question as I wanted it, but Wolfram visualization techniques never cease to amaze me!  This is an extraordinarily beautiful way visualize repeated matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one of those places where it really helps to know some linear algebra. Say you have a diagonalizable matrix (for example, any symmetric matrix) m. Then you can break it into Inverse[v].d.v where v are the eigenvectors and d is a diagonal matrix of the eigenvalues. Then powers of m have a nice form. For example:

```
m1 = RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, {2, 2}];
m = m1 + Transpose[m1]

{d, v} = Eigensystem[m]
```

Note that

```
Inverse[v] . DiagonalMatrix[d] . v // FullSimplify
```

is the same as m. More importantly,

```
Inverse[v] . (DiagonalMatrix[d]^2) . v // FullSimplify
```

is the same as m.m

and

```
Inverse[v] . (DiagonalMatrix[d]^n) . v
```

is the same as the matrix product of m taken n times. Since the middle term is a diagonal matrix, its power is just the power of the individual diagonal elements.  So you can see *all* powers of m using one formula.

When the matrix isn't diagonalizable, you can do an analogous thing using the Jordan form, but it's a bit more complicated.